# OS doesn't recognize harddisk at inital startup but after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, boot, software-raid, fdisk

I have a Debian 11 server with 4 HDD. Two of them are in a Raid 1 array.
When I shutdown the server completely and then turn it on again, the boot routine stops because it cannot find the Raid 1 device (the device is listed in fstab by it's UUID).
When I then logon and do fdsik -l I get only 2 of the HDDs listed, but not the ones from the Raid array. When I do then a reboot, the server comes up just fine showing all HDDs including the Raid 1 array /dev/md0.
What am I missing here?